# comparing array value to textbox input

Tags: php, forms, textbox

Couldn't find any solution on this yet, so I'm posting it here.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
//array: key=> value
$begrippen = array(
    "agrarisch" => "jagers en boeren",
    "cultuur" => "jagers en boeren",
    "jagers-verzamelaars" => "jagers en boeren",
    "landbouwsamenleving" => "jagers en boeren",
    "burgerschap" => "grieken en romeinen",
    "christendom" => "grieken en romeinen",
);
$message1 = 'Goedzo!';
$message2 = 'Fout!';

$random_key = array_rand($begrippen);
$value = $begrippen[$random_key];
echo "Begrip: $random_key <br />";
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="input1" autofocus>
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['input1'] == $value){
    echo "<SCRIPT> alert('$message1'); </SCRIPT>";
}else{
    echo "<SCRIPT> alert('$message2'); </SCRIPT>";
};
?>
```

It takes a random key from my array, takes the value and puts that in $value. When I enter input in my textbox, I want it to compare with $value and let it show a message (good or wrong). Yet something goes wrong and I don't know what because sometimes it says it's good, and sometimes it's wrong (while the answer was correct).

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: Where is your submit button ? You need to check whether the form is submitted or not.

Comment: Please explain your issue more...Where is the submit button...

Comment: Sorry, forgot the submit button in this code, but with submit button it wwasnt working either. The problem was, when I entered the correct value to random key shown, it still gave me message2(the wrong message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You can add **hidden** field in your form and assign the value to be refer.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="input1" autofocus>
    <input type="hidden" name="inputref" value="<?php echo $value;?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in PHP: your condition will be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   if($_POST['input1'] == $_POST['inputref']){
   ... Your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know without `form` submitting how this will work? So add a button as `submit` inside your `form`.

You need to do change your logic When `POST` request called.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['check'])){
    //array: key=> value
    $begrippen = array(
       "agrarisch" => "jagers en boeren",
       "cultuur" => "jagers en boeren",
       "jagers-verzamelaars" => "jagers en boeren",
       "landbouwsamenleving" => "jagers en boeren",
       "burgerschap" => "grieken en romeinen",
       "christendom" => "grieken en romeinen",
   );
   $message1 = 'Goedzo!';
   $message2 = 'Fout!';

   $random_key = array_rand($begrippen);
   $value = $begrippen[$random_key];
   echo "Begrip: $random_key <br />";
   if($_POST['input1'] == $value){
      echo "<SCRIPT> alert('$message1'); </SCRIPT>";
   }else{
      echo "<SCRIPT> alert('$message2'); </SCRIPT>";
   }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="input1" autofocus />
   <input type="submit" value="Check" name="check" />
</form>
```